# User Control Test Container: Assembly doesn't contain any UserControls

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

This is killing me. I'm trying to test/debug a WPF UserControl library in Visual Studio 2010 with the User Control Test Container.exe. I keep getting the error "Assembly [...] doesn't contain any UserControls." This should be simple, and every msdn article and blog tutorial I've looked at suggests that it should all just work perfectly and magically.

Here's the code for a very simple test case which I cannot make work:
XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <Label Content="Hello!" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="86,106,0,0" Name="Label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
</Grid>
```

Code Behind:

```
Public Class UserControl1
Inherits UserControl

    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

    End Sub

End Class
```

Project File has debug options set to open UserControlTestContainer.exe, with ./MyTestLibrary.dll as a command-line arg.

Any suggestions on how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure, your User control is being hosted in a Window or something right?  I am pretty certain you cannot display a usercontrol all by itself.  What does your containing window look like?

Comment: No, I don't have a containing Window, but I thought that was the whole point of User Control Test Container. It's a "WPF User Control Library", not a "WPF Application" so there's no "main" function, but from what I understand the UCTC generates a Window so that you can test UC components separately, without having to fire up the whole application. Was I wrong about this?

Comment: Just noticed that in the exceptionSystem.ArgumentException: Assembly './WpfControlLibrary_Tutorial1.dll' doesn't contain any UserControl types. at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.UserControlTestContainer.UserControlTestContainer_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   ...etc, UCTC is only using Forms Namespaces and not WPF namespaces. I'm going to take this to mean that UCTC is only really designed to work with WinForms UserControls, and not WPF UserControls. Thx for wasting three days of my life, Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

The [UserControl Test Container](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171738.aspx) is only for libraries build using the Windows Control Library Project Template. Even then, it's a subset since Visual C++ controls can't be tested using it.